Angular 16 - 'The theme for #{map.get($map, 'name')} does not contain #{$key}';
I am in the process of trying to upgrade from Angular version 15 to 16. After updating the necessary packages I am getting the error:
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined variable.
╷
117 │ @error 'The theme for #{map.get($map, 'name')} does not contain #{$key}';
│ ^^^^
╵
node_modules\igniteui-theming\sass\themes_functions.scss 117:41 var-get()
node_modules@infragistics\igniteui-angular\lib\core\styles\components\bottom-nav_bottom-nav-theme.scss 125:16 bottom-nav()
node_modules@infragistics\igniteui-angular\lib\core\styles\themes\generators_base.scss 155:9 theme-internal()
node_modules@infragistics\igniteui-angular\lib\core\styles\themes\generators_base.scss 42:5 theme()
node_modules@infragistics\igniteui-angular\lib\core\styles\themes\generators_base.scss 667:5 light-theme()
src\styles\rhi-light-theme.scss 6:3 @import
src\styles.scss 23:9 root stylesheet
My styles.scss is set as below:
//rhi styles
@import './styles/rhi';

// igx-color function has been renamed to color which is the same as the bootstrap function. Declare all infragistics colours before importing bootstrap.
// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// IMPORTANT: Make sure you always include igx-core first!
@include core();

// Configure application fonts with igx-typography
@include typography(
    $font-family: "'Montserrat', sans-serif",
    $type-scale: $rhi-type-scale
);

// Initialise ignite ui themes
@include theme($rhi-color-palette);

//Import rhi themes
@import './styles/rhi-light-theme';
@import './styles/rhi-dark-theme';

The issue seems to be specifically with:
$rhi-color-palette
in rhi.scss I have:
// Import the IgniteUI themes library first
@use '@infragistics/igniteui-angular/theming' as *;
@forward '@infragistics/igniteui-angular/theming';

// CSS Reset, comment out if not required or using a different module
@import 'node_modules/minireset.css/minireset';

// Import our defined palettes and schemas
@import './igx-palettes';
@import './igx-type-scales.scss';
.....

in igx-palettes.scss we have:
$rhi-color-palette: palette(
    $primary: $rhi-blue-color,
    $secondary: $rhi-pink-color,
    $surface: #fff,
    $info: color($light-material-palette, 'info'),
    $success: color($light-material-palette, 'success'),
    $error: color($light-material-palette, 'error'),
    $warn: color($light-material-palette, 'warn'),
);

$rhi-color-palette-dark: palette(
    $primary: $rhi-pink-color,
    $secondary: $rhi-pink-color,
    $gray: $white-color,
    $surface: #222,
    $info: color($light-material-palette, 'info'),
    $success: color($light-material-palette, 'success'),
    $error: color($light-material-palette, 'error'),
    $warn: color($light-material-palette, 'warn'),
);

and then in the light-theme.scss there is:
.rhi-light-theme {
  @include light-theme($rhi-color-palette);

.....
and in dark-theme.scss:
.rhi-dark-theme {
 @include dark-theme($rhi-color-palette-dark);

.....
I know it's to do with
$rhi-color-palette as if I remove these lines from styles.scss:
@include theme($rhi-color-palette);

@import './styles/rhi-light-theme';
@import './styles/rhi-dark-theme';

then the application will build.
And then also within the light theme file and dark theme files, if I remove the lines:
  @include light-theme($rhi-color-palette);
 @include dark-theme($rhi-color-palette-dark);

then I can still include the lines
@import './styles/rhi-light-theme';
@import './styles/rhi-dark-theme';

in styles.scss and it will build. So the issue seems to stem to how the palette is set up but I'm not sure what needs to change?

Figured out the issue. It wasn't anything to do with how the scss is set up but rather using an incompatible version of igniteui-theming. It had to be changed to version 3.3.3. Once this was don, I no longer got that error and it the application builds
